# Help with %es register for x86 to x86_64 assembly code port

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

Ok, I get this compile error:

> Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'

when I use this line:

```
pushw %es;
```

I know it is either the %es or w as I have been successfully porting others push, pop commands for 64 bit assembler.

`%es` is an existing register according to some documentaion I have found and isn't referenced differently I think.

So what could be my problem? I am extremely rusty on my asm and I think it could be the w.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you intend to use the segment registers in 64-bit mode? There are no segments.

Answer (score 2):

As Zimbaboa already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290000/248066), there is no segmentation in 64-bit mode.

Moreover, if you look at Intel's manuals, [Instruction Set Reference, M-Z](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/265667.pdf), you will see that `push ES` is an invalid instruction altogether in 64-bit mode (page 423):

```
Opcode  Instruction  Op/  64-Bit  Compat/  Description
                     En   Mode    Leg Mode
...
0E      PUSH CS      NP   Invalid Valid    Push CS. 
16      PUSH SS      NP   Invalid Valid    Push SS. 
1E      PUSH DS      NP   Invalid Valid    Push DS. 
06      PUSH ES      NP   Invalid Valid    Push ES. 
0F A0   PUSH FS      NP   Valid   Valid    Push FS. 
0F A8   PUSH GS      NP   Valid   Valid    Push GS.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the Pentium instruction set? If so, then yes, I think ES (capitalized) is a 16-bit segment register. The instruction is just "push %ES" according to this site: http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/index.htm. 
Wish I could help more, but I only code in MIPS assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using instruction `PUSHW` which is push word to stack. On 64bit machines wordsize is 64 and you are trying to push 16bit ES register using a wrong instruction.

Try just using `push`, but take care that your pop is also matching.

**Edit1:** Checked the [processor documentation](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24593.pdf), segmentation is disable in 64bit mode of x86_64

Check `section 4` of above document.

> 64-bit mode, segmentation is disabled, creating a flat 64-bit virtual-address space. As will be seen, certain functions of some segment registers, particularly the system-segment registers, continue to be used in 64-bit mode.

Again in `section 4.5.3`

> DS, ES, and SS Registers in 64-Bit Mode.  In 64-bit mode, the contents of the ES, DS, and SS segment registers are ignored. All fields (base, limit, and attribute) in the hidden portion of the segment registers are ignored.

So in your code just safely ignore any references to these registers.

Comment: Tried this and I am still getting the same issue. Maybe the operand then as when I change %es to es it doesn't spit out an error but I believe it would no longer be referring to the extra segment register.

Comment: #define save_context()    \
 push %rbp;           \
 mov %rsp, %rbp;      \
 push %rdi;           \
 push %rsi;           \
 push %rbx;           \
 pushw %es;            \
 pushw %fs;            \

Comment: Thanks Zimbabao, what documentation did you use? Intel, AMD? or a  more generic compilation of the two?

Comment: I saw AMD. I have given link for it in the answer it self. Regarding resgisters both should not differ anyway